# How to use/test pivot_root?

Tags: linux, chroot, docker

I want to test the [`pivot_root`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pivot_root.8.html) command which moves the root file system of the current process to the directory `put_old` and makes `new_root` the new root file system.

*But I always get the following error:*

```
pivot_root: failed to change root from .' toold-root/': Invalid argument
```

I use fedora as base root, I have a Archlinux in my home folder

```
[root@localhost arch-root]# ls
bin boot dev etc home lib lib64 mnt old-root 
opt proc root run sbin srv sys tmp usr var
[root@localhost arch-root]# pivot_root . old-root/
pivot_root: failed to change root from .' toold-root/': Invalid argument
```

I also try to call linux function `pivot_root("/chroot_test", "/chroot_test/old-root")`; Got same error.

Any ideas about this ?

#### Update #1

I also try to test `pivot_root` in Docker. I mount this arch-root in to Docker container. But get the following error: `Operation not permitted`

```
root@00d871ce892b:/# cd test_root/
root@00d871ce892b:/test_root# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  mnt  old-root  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv     sys  test_pivot_root  test_pivot_root.c   tmp  usr  var
root@00d871ce892b:/test_root# pivot_root . tmp/
pivot_root: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: From the sound of this post it sounds like a bug to me: https://github.com/lxc/lxc/issues/61. This thread too sounds related: https://lists.linuxcontainers.org/pipermail/lxc-users/2014-January/006124.html

Comment: Yea I am trying to test the function of Docker and lxc feature which use pivot_root

Answer (score 6):

Are you really sure that `arch-root` is on a separate filesystem that can be mounted and umounted?

`pivot_root`, as well as the more current `switch_root`, works by juggling information about mounted filesystems in the kernel.

The new root file system must be "the root" of a file system, you cannot pass "." as the new root unless "." is the root directory of a mounted filesystem.

I believe the easiest way if you want to try `pivot_root` from your current setup (assuming arch-root is a subdirectory and not a root directory) is to create a `tmpfs` filesystem to switch to, and copy the required stuff there.

Something along these lines might get you started: (adjust 500M to fit `du -sh arch-root`)

```
mkdir /ramroot
mount -n -t tmpfs -o size=500M none /ramroot
cd arch-root # (containing the root filesystem contents)
find . -depth -xdev -print | cpio -pd --quiet /ramroot
cd /ramroot
mkdir oldroot
pivot_root . oldroot
exec chroot . bin/sh
```

Comment: Thank you very much, For now I am testing it in a docker container. it works. I will try your method later

Comment: I think there is a much more minimal way to satisfy this requirement, `mount --bind /chroot-test /chroot-test && cd /chroot-test`.  (The second part makes sure that `.` refers to the new /chroot-test, not the old /chroot-test). This is according to http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/switch_root.8.html#NOTES

Comment: You might need to do an `unshare -m` before the pivot_root. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1361043

Answer (score 4):

From the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pivot_root.2.html), I believe this is your issue:

```
The following restrictions apply to new_root and put_old:

- They must be directories.

- new_root and put_old must not be on the same file system as the current
root.

- put_old must be underneath new_root, that is, adding a nonzero number of
/.. to the string pointed to by put_old must yield the same directory as
new_root.

- No other file system may be mounted on put_old.
```

According to the above neither `put_old` or `new_root` filesystems should reside on the same filesystem as `current_root`.

#### References

- [How to mount final root filesystem after loading initrd?](http://forum.nas-central.org/viewtopic.php?f=61&t=7959)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I update the question. I also try to test in Docker. But Operation not permitted

Comment: Your summary is wrong. `new_root` and `put_old` *can* be on the same FS, it's just that neither should reside on the same FS *as the current root*.

Comment: @iBug - ty fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The author of the question provided this solution:

> #### Solution
>
> I have found **the solution:**
>
> Run `docker` with `--privileged=true`
>
> So we can test pivot_root in the docker container.